# Change the height dynamically due to the width of a div

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to set a height to a `<div>` so that if height resized, the width will re-size equally e.g. if the width of a `<div>` is being reduced via the user re-sizing a browser window, the height will be reduced in the same proportion.

How is this possible?

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: @ketan it's possible without JS? OP requests help with HTML and CSS only.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Were any of the suggestions able to help you?

Comment: @scniro Yes, sorry I won't be abe to answer it before because I was working. I got the solution with the question marked as duplicate so I am going to mark it as duplicate because it solved me the problem. Thank you for your answer too!

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution with an image.

HTML

```
<div>
  <img src="transparent-image.png" alt=""/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  div { display: inline-block; }
  img { max-width: 100%; }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ilyabogdanov/mgx0xcxs/3/)

Comment: can you get this to work without an image?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. This example is JavaScript free but will require a parent element. Observe the following...

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
#container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
#container:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100%;
}
#element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

Whenever width is changed, so is height, equally. Supplied below is a demo, while using jQuery, is just for an easy way to manipulate the element width.

```
// -- 100 x 100
$('#container').click(function() {
    $(this).width(50); // -- 50 x 50
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/tkm3t643/) - demo

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/2hbc05mL/) - additional demo - `%` based - (re-size output window to see scaling)

Additionally, for a short and much simpler answer, use `vw` units. Observe the following...

```
<div></div>
```

---

```
div {
    width:20vw;
    height:20vw;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/0u7sv4ka/) - `vw` demo

[Here](https://www.weareconvoy.com/2014/07/css-vw-and-vh-units-are-they-worth-using-yet/) is a decent writeup on `vw` and other similar units that may be of interest

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if it is possible with only css and html, since window resizeing is dynamic.I have created this snippet for demo and you can change according to your convience.Hope this code will be useful.

HTML

```
<div class="defaultDimen" id='defaultDiv'>
    Hello Default Div
</div>
```

CSS

```
.defaultDimen{
    height:30%;
    width:20%;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-radius:6px;

}
```

JS & jQuery

```
function _resizeDiv(options){
var ratio=options.ratio;
    var elem = $(options.element);
    var _getWidth = elem.width();
    var _getHeight = elem.height();

    elem.css({'width':'30%',
              'height':elem.width()*ratio})

}

$(window).resize(function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('defaultDiv');
    _resizeDiv({
     ratio:0.5,
        element:elem
    })
})
```

You can specify the ratio of height & width you want.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqeo6kmo/)

Comment: see my answer for a JS free solution